# How does one prevent mypy from getting angry at kwargs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Suppose I define a function:

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional

def foo(
    this: Optional[int], 
    is: Optional[str], 
    worse: Optional[datetime], 
    than: Optional[float], 
    C: Optional[bool] = True, 
    **kwargs
):
    print("for no apparent, valid reason!")

foo(100,**{'C':True})
```

`mypy` anger:

```
Argument 2 to "foo" has incompatible type ...
```

But, if I defined the values with default args, I can't override them with `kwargs` without triggering errors like `multiple values for "worse" were found` before I recover control in the body of the function.

How do I get around this `mypy` anger?

Comment: Your function definition results in a syntax error ("is" is a keyword), and your example usage of your function fails at runtime even if we replace the "is" parameter with "is_" (you fail to provide values for your "is_", "worse" or "than" parameters). Could you provide us with a minimal example that does not fail at runtime and that we can reproduce in Mypy playground? https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10

Comment: @AlexWaygood I freehanded it.  Surely you got the gist.

Comment: Not really, no.

Comment: @AlexWaygood Sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

[Just annotate kwargs with type of values in corresponding dict](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html#when-you-re-puzzled-or-when-things-are-complicated)

```py
# This makes each positional arg and each keyword arg a "str"
def call(self, *args: str, **kwargs: str) -> str:
    request = make_request(*args, **kwargs)
    return self.do_api_query(request)
```

In your case I would suggest to use `Union`-type or `Any`. Beside of that, you probably better look at [`@overloading`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#function-overloading) if you need somehow to use function with multiple sets of arguments.

> multiple values for "worse" were found

Or you could declare `worse` as a keyword-only argument:

```py
def foo(
    this: Optional[int], 
    is: Optional[str], 
    than: Optional[float], 
    C: Optional[bool] = True, 
    *,
    worse: Optional[datetime], 
    **kwargs,
): ...
```

avoiding ambigous situations like

```py
foo('this', 'is', **{'is': 'also is??'})
```